# Error on update entity with Hibernate Entity Listener

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have created in my app one `AuditorAware` to when I save my entity he automatic set the  logged User and date with annotations `@CreatedBy` and `@CreatedDate`, so when I save the entity works fine, but When I try to UPDATE I got an java.lang.StackOverflowError

my Class

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SecurityAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<Usuario> {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    @Override
    public Optional<Usuario> getCurrentAuditor() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return usuarioRepository.findByLogin(((User)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
    }
}
```

I tried first to load the entity with `myRepository.findById(id)`, and create an empty and setter a existing ID and then in both `myRepository.save()`

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:120) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.findByLogin(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.anoregrn.rtdpjback.audit.SecurityAuditorAware.getCurrentAuditor(SecurityAuditorAware.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
```